# Is there a way to mark rows in SQL Server as "inactive"?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We have an app using SQL Server (Azure SQL). Operations Department is requesting a way to avoid processing of some rows (on demand, various reasons, various tables). So row data should be kept but made "invisible" for standard selects, updates, etc. In some cases Operations will re-activate the row after some time (issue is solved, etc.) to continue processing. In other cases they would keep the row inactive forever.

Is there any built-in feature of SQL Server to help us directly in the database? Like [this archiving in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/control-validity-visibility-data.html#GUID-5A76B6CE-C96D-49EE-9A89-0A2CB993A933). I would like to avoid addition of `ACTIVE = true/false` column to many tables - such approach would lead to `ACTIVE` checking in the app persistence layer whenever we touch the data (not nice, hard to maintain).

Comment: You're stuck with adding a column and filtering in the app really. I suppose you could add the column and then make views that your app uses rather than the tables.

Comment: add a column, add a view on top - use the view for queries. that excludes those with whatever in that column.  Making "invisible" for normal selects is done through a specific where clause f.e. if you got various changing reasons to do it.

Comment: There is no built in method, no. You could, however, add a column that is a `bit` type with perhaps `1` as "active" and `0` not. But you'll need to update any (and all) queries appropriately to omit rows with `0`/include only those with `1` in the column. As such, you could therefore create `VIEW`s which filter these automatically, but just make sure that you don't nest them in any definitions as performance can quickly fall.

Comment: Although it's not *quite* the same thing, you could achieve this by "creatively" using system-versioned history tables. "Archiving" can then be done with a `DELETE`, and "unarchiving" is inserting the row back from the history table. Of course this does not work if your data has regular `DELETE` operations for rows that must *not* reappear, as you can't distinguish between those (though you could set a separate "archived" flag first, I suppose). As others have mentioned, using views with indexes is an option, but for a binary view like this physically separate tables tend to perform better.

Comment: The only way I can think of to avoid making app level changes is a convoluted row level security approach.

Comment: I have similar requirements for some parts of an application. The only solution we were comfortable with using was implementing a flag on the tables that needed data being restricted based on business logic and applications using views to access data where the view honoured the status of the flag. However we had the luxury of building this as part of the design, not cludging it in at a later date.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think your idea suits us best. We actually never really delete the data (even old entries are valuable for our customer). Entries can be just inactivated for standard app workflow. So there could be an archive table for "hidden" entries - one for each table we want this feature in. I would migrate the data from "live" table to archive table using a trigger on DELETE operation. Or is there a better way to implement it using this approach?

Comment: Well, when I said system-versioned history tables I meant the [built-in feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables). Aside from setting it up you wouldn't need to do anything special on a `DELETE` as the engine would do it for you. As a bonus, or drawback, depending on your needs and your storage (but note that you can compress the history table, and probably should), you would also have full update history of the rows. A roll-your-own approach with a trigger does work, of course, and is a bit more flexible.

Comment: Yes @JeroenMostert has the best idea - system versioned tables. It is native functionallity, you don't need triggers, you don't need to change your app.

Answer (score 0):

Would Row level security be a possibility for you? Simply restrict an access to the rows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That's part of an answer, but ideally you should provide a little more than just a linkdrop to demonstrate how this would work in practice. It's not *that* simple, and there's the problem that row-level security tends to be very finicky about using indexes properly for efficient access. This becomes an issue especially if there are many "archived" rows, since they're merely not returned by the engine rather than truly out of the way.

Comment: This approach is based on user roles right? So administrator can forbid some user to access given row. I don't see a solution there.

Because we need a user (like some Operations guy) to hide some row for everybody. And the (eventually) to make it reappear for everybody. While the row should still be "searchable" even when hidden - like in case of Oracle feature I have linked above. You can set `ROW ARCHIVAL VISIBILITY = ALL` and see everything or `VISIBILITY = ACTIVE` and see just what is not hidden.

Comment: @Mamut: RLS is not based on roles per se but on filter predicates; the function that determines if a row is visible can be anything, it doesn't even have to involve the user. In particular, it could check for a specific value in `SESSION_CONTEXT` to see if the "see archived rows" flag is set, which gets you close to what Oracle does.

Comment: @Mamut, there is no such a build-in feature in SQL Server. There are some possibilities to implement a workaround, one of them is adding a column to the table reflecting YES or NO state and another one is to restrict an access to the specific rows, the logical filter has to be implemented into application (query has to check YES \ NO) if or into database (using Security policy for RLS and creating something like SPs to run in different contexts, as an example). This way you would have hidden rows still searchable. But it's a lot of design, testing and developing.

Comment: Actually as per @Jeroen Mostert's idea, there is: temporal tables. These would appear to satisfy all requirements.